# Clone C++ datatype for multiplatform purposes

Tags: c++, multithreading, cross-platform

I have an idea how to make very simple crossplatform (linux/windows) thread function. This is my sample code:

```
#if LINUX
 #include <pthread.h>
 ThreadHandle createThread(???* callback, void* data) {   //I dont know what is data type of function pointer, sorry
     pthread_t handle;
     pthread_create(&handle, 0, callback, (void*)data);
     return (ThreadHandle)handle;
 }
 define_data_type ThreadHandle = pthread_t;  //I don't know how this is done at all, sorry
#endif
#if WINDOWS
  #include <windows.h>
  ThreadHandle createThread(???* callback, void* data) {
        HANDLE handle = CreateThread( 
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        callback,               // thread function name
        data,                   // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        NULL);   // returns the thread identifier - I don't need this, do I?
  }
  define_data_type ThreadHandle = HANDLE;  //I don't know how this is done at all, sorry
#endif
```

I'm afraid this will first look like veird question, but keep on mind that I'm **beginner**, and I need to understand C++. Feel free to **edit** those parts where I left *"i don't know"* comments.
If you think this is wrong question, please leave comment about how should I've asked.

Comment: Does [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) work in all of your environments?

Comment: Wow, that std:: looks like cure for everything. Everytime I seek something multiplatform, someone shows up with std:: function. Thank you very much. But I'm still interested how to do this cross platform stuff.

Comment: If you're curious or your environment is not yet C++11, you could take a look at Boost, which contains a thread wrapper class which is ported to many different OSs.

Comment: I'm trying to install boost, but since it [resists my best efforts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695517/building-boost-bjam-cannot-find-g), I'm looking for different solutions.

Comment: To make it fair, `std::thread` decided not to work either: `#include <thread>` takes no effect and keeps `std::thread` undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start by having a platform independent header like Thread.h which will abstract all the thread functions
2. Have platform specific code in *.$platform.cpp files
3. Obviously your build system should only compile platform relevant code

Now, for specific code

Use something like this to define generic types

typedef unsigned long os_error_t;

```
typedef void * os_console_handle;
typedef void * os_thread_handle;
typedef void * os_event_handle;
typedef unsigned long os_pid_t;
typedef unsigned long os_thread_id;
```

On linux, use  and call pthread_create(..)
On windows, use  and call CreateThread(..) 
Read the docs for specific impl

For callback you can use something like

```
typedef os_error_t (*thread_start_function_t)(void *);

class InternalThreadArgs {
    thread_start_function_t m_func;
    void *m_pArg;
public:
    InternalThreadArgs(thread_start_function_t pf, void *pArg) {
        m_func = pf;
        m_pArg = pArg;
    }
    os_error_t Run() {
        return m_func(m_pArg);
    }
};
```

Now, 
have your abstract method signatures like

```
     os_error_t create_thread(thread_start_function_t pf, void *pArg, os_thread_handle *pHandle);
```

Comment: Seems `typedef` was what I am looking for. Using multiple us good point - surelly I will need more multiplatform functions.